# Связывание таблиц sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite3

Есть 2 таблицы , абитуриенты и специальности. Они связаны по полю Specialty.

```
CREATE TABLE "Applicants" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "UID"   TEXT,
    "Lastname"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Secondname"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "AverageScore"  REAL NOT NULL,
    "Specialty" INTEGER,
    "Benefit"   INTEGER DEFAULT 0 CHECK("Benefit" IN (0, 1)),
    "Diploma"   INTEGER DEFAULT 0 CHECK("Diplomal" IN (0, 1)),
    "Medal" INTEGER DEFAULT 0 CHECK("Medal" IN (0, 1)),
    "BirthDate" TEXT,
    "PhoneNumber"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "ScoreSetted"   INTEGER DEFAULT 0 CHECK("ScoreSetted" IN (0, 1)),
    "CalcAvS"   REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    FOREIGN KEY("Specialty") REFERENCES "Specialties"("Id_Sp") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE "Specialties" (
    "Id_Sp" INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Places"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id_Sp" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Но при запуске такого кода выдает исключение

```
db.Specialties.Add(new Specialty("ТЭФ", 100));
db.SaveChanges();
db.Applicants.Add(new Applicant(" ", "f", "a", "c", 4, 1 , 0, 0, 1,  "22.10.2002", "44-44-44"));
db.SaveChanges();

class Specialty
    {
        public int Id_Sp { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Places { get; set; }

        public Specialty() { }

        public Specialty(
                 string Name,
                 int Places
            )
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Places = Places;
        }
    }
```

: EntityType 'Specialty' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Код специальности я вписываю после аргумента цифры 4, я рассуждаю так : я добавил одну специальность и у нее код автоматически соответственно 1, и ее кидаю абитуриенту, но как я понял это так не работает. Как мне это сделать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Applicant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } public string Secondname{ get; set; } public string Lastname{ get; set; }
       
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }

        public string UID { get; set; }
        public double AverageScore { get; set; }

        public double CalcAvS { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        //public int Specialty { get; set; }


        //public List<Specialty> Specialties { get; set; }
        public Specialty Specialty { get; set; }
        public int Benefit { get; set; }
        //public int Specialty_Id { get; set; }
        public int Diploma { get; set; }

        public int Medal { get; set; }
        public int ScoreSetted { get; set; }

        /*public string Name {
            get { return Name; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }
        public string Secondname_Action
        {
            get { return Secondname; }
            set { Secondname = value; }
        }
        public string Lastname_Action
        {
            get { return Lastname; }
            set { Lastname = value; }
        }
        public double Av_Score_Action
        {
            get { return AverageScore; }
            set { AverageScore = value; }
        }*/
        public Applicant() { }
        public Applicant(string UID,
            string Lastname, 
            string Name, string Secondname, 
            double AverageScore,
            int Benefit,
            int Diploma,
            int Medal,
            string BirthDate,
            string PhoneNumber
            ) {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Secondname = Secondname;
            this.Lastname = Lastname;
            this.AverageScore = AverageScore;
            this.CalcAvS = AverageScore;
            this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
            this.Benefit = Benefit;
            this.Diploma = Diploma;
            this.Medal = Medal;
            this.BirthDate = BirthDate;
            this.UID = UID;
        }
    }

class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Specialty> Specialties { get; set; }
        public AppContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

        /*protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().HasRequired(current => current.Specialty)
                .WithMany(c => c.Applicants)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.Specialty_Id)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }*/
        //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        //=> options.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");
    }
```

Comment: Приведите код класса Specialties, возможно, проблема в нём. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203492/entitytype-has-no-key-defined-error

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov, подписал

Comment: Если вы используете в качестве первичного ключа свойство, имя которого отлично от Id или <type name>Id, вы должны маркировать свойство особым образом с помощью [Key] или особой Fluent-нотации. Подробнее в https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov, та ошибка пропала ,теперь при добавлении абитуриента вот это: SQLiteException: constraint failed
CHECK constraint failed: Applicants

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov, я просто на Id исправил название  у специальности , если что

Comment: У вас в таблице Applicants есть столбцы типа int, которые используются как bool. CHECK constraint объявлен именно для них. Я думаю, что ошибка связана с этим ограничением, но вообще это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov, нет, проблема не в этом, потому что до этого все работало нормально , и я перепроверил, ошибок в этом никаких нет. Я думал о PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0; но я посмотрел, это включено. Добавлю на всякий случай скрины таблиц, уже и не знаю что думать:(

Comment: Покажите код класса `Applicant`. И код класс-контекста. / Вы должны предоставить такой код, чтобы его можно было скопировать и запустить. Тогда вы быстро получите ответ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, : SQL logic error
table Applicants has no column named Specialty_Id. Я так понимаю это оно так должно называться? Просто у меня это поле есть и оно называется просто Specialty

Answer (score 0):

Давайте упростим код, чтобы было легче разобраться. Уберём большинство свойств, оставив необходимый минимум.

```
class Specialty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; } = new HashSet<Applicant>();
}
class Applicant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Specialty Specialty { get; set; }
}
```

На одной специальности может быть множество абитуриентов. У каждого абитуриента есть одна специальность. Я правильно понял ваш замысел?

Класс контекста:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Specialty> Specialties { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");
}
```

Стандартный способ работы:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    //db.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var applicant = new Applicant { Name = "App1" };

    var specialty = new Specialty { Name = "Spec1" };
    specialty.Applicants.Add(applicant);

    db.Specialties.Add(specialty);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Тут будут вставлены две записи в таблицы и между ними создана правильная связь.

---

Не нужно гадать, какой id будет назначен вставленной сущности. Нужно правильно использовать возможности фреймворка.

Comment: у меня нет DbContextOptionsBuilder , при попытке установить Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore ошибка Не удалось установить пакет «Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета.

Comment: @ДаниилСорокин - почему этого нет в самом вопросе? Почему вы пишете это в комментариях? Вся необходимая информация должна содержаться в вопросе: какую платформу используете, какие библиотеки (с указанием точных версий) и т. п.

Comment: @ДаниилСорокин - ну, хорошо, замените `OnConfiguring` на тот способ задания строки соединения, который используется в вашей версии EF. Всё остальное от этого не меняется.

Comment: @ДаниилСорокин - вся суть содержится в блоке кода под заголовком "Стандартный способ работы".

Comment: public AppContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }  , может дело в том как я подключаюсь к бд?

Comment: @ AlexanderPetrov, теперь ошибка SQLiteException: constraint failed
CHECK constraint failed: Applicants, мне вообще не понятно откуда